# SetObjectAsJson and GetObjectFromJson not showing as part of HttpContext.Session in .NET Core 1.0

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm worried that this is a rookie mistake, but I've been searching and I can't find anything related to this.

I have a .NET Core v1.0 Web App that I build for an intranet application. It's been through user tests and deployed to production.

A user pointed out a small bug today. I have migrated Workspaces in VS2015 since deploying, so  I downloaded the project. On initial build I'm getting the CS1061 Error stating that `SetObjectAsJson` is not part of `ISession`. Here is the offending Code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(DateTime? beginDate, DateTime? endDate, string currentLocation)
    {       

        var userId = this.User.Identity.Name;
        var userEmail = userId.Remove(0, 11) + "@roystonllc.com";
        var querystring = this.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Value;
        var ex = _context.Engineer.Where(x => x.sEmail == userEmail);
        var engineer = await ex.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("Engineer", engineer);
```

All references of SetObjectAsJson and GetObjectFromJson are showing invalid. 
Here are the services added in Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        var connection = @"Server=THESERVER;Database=THEDATABASE;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=false;User ID=THEUSER;Password=THEPASSWORD";
        services.AddDbContext<SCHEDULEContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddMvcGrid();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache
        services.AddSession();


    }
```

Here is my project.json:

```
    {
    "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
    "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
   "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
//"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
//"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions": "1.0.0",
"NonFactors.Grid.Mvc6": "1.3.0",
"NonFactors.Grid.Core.Mvc6": "1.3.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
},

    "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
//"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
},

"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "imports": [
      "dotnet5.6",
      "portable-net45+win8"
    ]
  }
},

"buildOptions": {
  "emitEntryPoint": true,
  "preserveCompilationContext": true
},

"runtimeOptions": {
  "configProperties": {
    "System.GC.Server": true
  }
},

"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "**/*.cshtml",
    "appsettings.json",
    "web.config"
  ]
},

"scripts": {
  "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
  "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SetObjectAsJson` and `GetObjectFromJson` are not part of ASP.NET Core. They are extension methods that originate probably from [this](http://benjii.me/2016/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnetcore-and-mvc-core/) article. Try textual search through your solution, perhaps the library they sit in is just not referenced properly.

Otherwise, add the following class to your project:

```c#
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void SetObjectAsJson(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static T GetObjectFromJson<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);

        return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Note that the code (`JsonConvert`) depends on Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package so you might have to add that reference as well.

Comment: thank you!  I was right, this was a rookie mistake. 

I already had the JsonConvert package, so I obviously searched for a way to store objects in the session months ago, and somehow that change didn't get checked in. 

Do you have any suggestions on where to place an extension class like like this for good code organization?

Comment: Haha :) Sometimes it's not easy to find a good place for extension methods. I typically end up placing them in a folder called "Extensions" (just under the root folder) and I try to keep them organized by the namespace or type they relate to (e.g.""IOExtensions", "StringExtensions", or "DateTimeExtensions").

Comment: I think it's more important to put them in the right assembly. If the extensions relate only to .NET types/namespaces, I think it's ok to put them in a single separate assembly. If the extensions relate to your custom types, they should be placed in assemblies beside those types.

Comment: Is there a particular namespace where this class needs to fit in relation to where it is being used? In my case I am trying to use the extension attribute on Session in a service.

Comment: No, just reference your namespace from the code that's calling the extensions.