# .net core 3.1 HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString and .GetString throwing InvalidOperationException

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to configure the session in .net core 3.1. When I call the following

HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString
HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString

I get the following exception

System.InvalidOperationException: "Session has not been configured for this application or request"

I followed the article : https://benjii.me/2016/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnetcore-and-mvc-core/

and
[SetObjectAsJson and GetObjectFromJson not showing as part of HttpContext.Session in .NET Core 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790892/setobjectasjson-and-getobjectfromjson-not-showing-as-part-of-httpcontext-session)

In my startup.cs,

I got the services.UseSession(); def before services.UseMvc();

In my class constructor is see the error when I place the pointer the constructor parameter for dependency injection

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
public MyClass
{
  public MyClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
  {
    var session = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
  }
}
```

The error is  httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session threw an exception of type System.InvalidOperationException

In my startup.cs I got services order as following

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
  services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
  services.AddSession();
  
  services.AddMvc().AddXmLDataContractSerializerFormatters();
  services.AddMemoryCache();
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You could refer the official document to configure session in asp.net core: [Configure session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1) (please note the session IdleTimeout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `app.UseSession();` in `Configure` method in startup class

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //
    app.UseSession();
}
```

Your startup class should be like this

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
  services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
  services.AddSession();
  
  services.AddMvc().AddXmLDataContractSerializerFormatters();
  services.AddMemoryCache();
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //
    app.UseSession();
}
```

**NOTE:** You don't need to use `app.UseMvc();` in `.Net Core 3.0` or higher